# Why does this code crash the second time it is executed in FSI?

Tags: dictionary, f#, fsi

I have some code that generates an exception the `second time`  it is executed in FSI. The sequence is the following:

1) Select all lines `above` it, run on `FSI` using `Alt+Enter`.

2) Select the code, run on `FSI` using `Alt+Enter`. So far no errors.

3) Run the selected code again by hitting `Alt+Enter`. Error (see below).

Here are the lines of code generating this behavior:

```
let assetsMap =
    assetInfo.Rows
    |> Seq.filter (fun (rw: AssetsInfo.Row) -> Set.contains rw.Ticker assetsTickerSet)
    |> List.ofSeq
    |> List.map (fun rw -> rw.Ticker, Asset.constructor rw) // Frame.ReadCSV called here
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

Relevant info:

```
type AssetsInfo = FSharp.Data.CsvProvider<...>
```

Error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: tried to skip The input sequence has an insufficient number of elements. 1 past the end of the seq
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Skip@1316.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   at FSharp.Data.Runtime.CsvHelpers.parseIntoTypedRows@176.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\Git\FSharp.Data\src\Csv\CsvRuntime.fs:line 176
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.next@187[T](FSharpFunc`2 f, IEnumerator`1 e, FSharpRef`1 started, Unit unitVar0)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.filter@182.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0035>.$FSI_0035.main@() in H:\Dropbox\BitBucket\VSProjects\Fractal10\Fractal10\Program.fs:line 139
Stopped due to error
```

Any ideas on the reason for this odd behavior?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the type provider.

Comment: I concur; I suggest [reporting this as a bug](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues) in the FSharp.Data project.

Comment: @rmunn - I reported it.